# qsort dynamically created array in c

Tags: c, struct, qsort

Hey guys (be forewarned that this question makes me feel n00b so I probably am),

I'm able to dynamically create an array and I'm able to use qsort effectively for a statically created array but am having trouble using qsort on a dynamically created one. I think I'm stumbling on my use of pointers.

```
struct my_struct {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
};
```

So the array contains the above struct and I'd like to sort it by the int value.

Statically, I can do something like this:

```
struct my_struct array[4];
```

And sort:

```
qsort((void *) &array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(struct my_struct), sizeof(struct my_struct), *compare);
```

--

If I create the array thus:

```
struct my_struct* = malloc(sizeof(struct process) * 4);
```

Everything compiles and runs, however execution never goes into the compare function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I assume you mean `struct my_struct *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * 4);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sizeof(array) is (sizeof(struct my_struct) * array_size) for constant-size array, but it's only pointer size for dynamic one. You have to calculate actual size (one you passed to malloc) yourself and put it into qsort call.

Comment: Thanks ^_^ that was a fairly dumb move on my part

Answer (score 2):

Your invocation of `qsort` only works by accident:

```
qsort((void *) &array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(struct my_struct), sizeof(struct my_struct), *compare);
```

The address of an array has the same value but a different type from the address of the zeroth element of the array.  The cast to `void *` is also superfluous; and the dereference of the comparator function is also aconventional.  Normally, that'd be written:

```
qsort(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(struct my_struct), compare);
```

Or:

```
qsort(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(array[0]), compare);
```

If you have a dynamically allocated structure:

```
size_t num_items = 4;
struct my_struct *dynarr = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct) * num_items);
```

or:

```
struct my_struct *dynarr = malloc(sizeof(*dynarr) * num_items);
```

then you will be specifying the number of elements differently in the call to `qsort`, but the rest is essentially unchanged:

```
qsort(dynarr, num_items, sizeof(*dynarr), compare);
```

Note in particular that there is no `&` in front of `dynarr`, which is a simple pointer variable, for all it has a possibly misleading name.

---

#### Why your code went wrong

*A guess, but a plausible guess.*  If you wrote:

```
qsort(&dynarr, sizeof(dynarr) / sizeof(dynarr[0]), sizeof(dynarr[0]), compare);
```

then `sizeof(dynarr)` is the size of a pointer (say 8 bytes in a 64-bit program), and `sizeof(dynarr[0])` is 16 bytes, so the size (number of elements) that you tell `qsort()` to sort is 0 (because `8 / 16 == 0`), so the comparator would never be called.  If your program is compiled as a 32-bit program, the sizes are 4 bytes for the pointer and 8 for the structure, so the result is still 0.

Note that if instead you passed `4` or `num_items` as the size of the array, then you'd get a crash.  The address of `dynarr` is the wrong address to pass to the function; you want to pass the address value that is held in `dynarr`, not the address at which `dynarr` itself is stored.

NB: You should show the `qsort()` that doesn't work so we don't have to guess what you've written.